# Mass and Volume increase

Tags: special-relativity, mass, volume

Under relativity, does the mass AND volume of a body increase with increasing speed, or is it just the mass increasing. as in "getting denser"? My apologies, if this is a trivial question.....

Comment: Mass does not increase with speed. Relativistic mass is a terribly outdated and blatantly incorrect concept.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Looks like I'm behind the times..... :):)

Answer (score 2):

Relativistic mass is a long discarded concept. The modern usage is that the unqualified term “mass” refers to the invariant mass which does not increase with increasing speed.

That said, the energy increases and the volume decreases due to length contraction. So the energy density increases. So it does get “denser” in that sense.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Looks like I'm behind the times..... :):)